# Where to put data for select boxes in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

If I have table in database like this:

```
users
    id
    username
    status
```

and status can be:

status
    0 - not active
    1 - active
    2 - banned

where should I put statuses, i have some possibilities:

1. in repository pattern for users
2. in User Eloquent class
3. in helpers
4. in database (sometimes I would create 50 more tables for this and I don't think this is good idea)
5. in controller constructor and share it like "View::share('select', $usersStatuses);" i think this is not clean and elegant solution.

?

EDITED:

{!! Form::select('status', user_statuses(), @$user->status, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}

Look at function "user_statuses()" where and how this should get data  ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest 2, and like this

```
class User extends Model
{
    const STATUS_BANNED= 2;
    const STATUS_INACTIVE = -1;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 1;
}
```

Model access property like User::STATUS_ACTIVE, it is clear.

Comment: I appredicate but I am looking for solution where I can use this data for select box like: {!! Form::select('status', user_statuses(), @$user->status, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
with your solution I can't get all statuses in array for select box.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understand now. IMHO, the best approach is helper class with static function for getting user statuses.

```
Class UserHelper
{
    public static function getStatuses() { 
        return [
              0 => not_active, 
              1 => active,
              2 => banned
        ];
    }
}

UserHelper::getStatuses();
```

Pros:

- You don't need initialize User object for getting statuses.
- You can use it in the Controller and View too.

Comment: not good, because I have controller for backend and frontend and both use same data and with your approach I need to use this code in both controllers and this is not DRY.

Comment: It is not problem that I don't know hot to achive this, problem is what is best and most elegant approach.